# How to get resource value from C# .resources.dll in "powershell"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

During Powershell implementation i want to get the resource value from language specific resources dll , and the resource file is available inside "en-US", "de-DE",... folders

Answer (score 1):

following is the example powershell script fro de-De resource reading

```bsh
$de_DE_ResourceAssembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("<full Path to resources.dll e.g ...\bin\de-DE\snapin.resources.dll >")
$manifestName =  $de_DE_ResourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
$rm = new-object -typename System.Resources.ResourceManager -ArgumentList $manifestName.Replace('.resources',''), $de_DE_ResourceAssembly
$culture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
$rm.GetString("<Resource key>",$culture)
```